# I was robbed by Upwork, what do I do?

Tags: freelance-websites

I've been happily using Upwork three years ago as a freelancer. Recently I've logged in again and tried as a client. I had one contract performed successfully and had money in escrow for the second one; however, my account suddenly got blocked and after a week long fruitless correspondence with support team (which were replying exactly once in 48 hours) got removed completely for being linked to  another account. I've managed to contact my freelancer through another platform and he says that the contract was cancelled and he did not get paid. I did not get any refund either (it all happened a week ago) and what's worse I can't even contact Upwork support anymore because I don't have an account there. I heard rumors Upwork can do things like this, now I went through it myself and I can join those who in no way recommend this platform neither as a client nor as a freelancer, but my question to the community is: is there any chance or any way to get my money back and how?

Comment: Sometimes the freelancing sites like Upwork and Fiverr behave in this way, and their support team is also very slow with the replies
So what you can do is you need to keep contacting the support team, that's the only way you can retrieve your money back

Comment: @MurtazaA There might be another option: Sue them.

Answer (score 4):

You should ideally engage the services of a business ombudsman if one exists in your locality. Failing that, a business focussed legal organisation.

If upwork hasn’t given you a fair experience, you should be entitled to compensation.